# Take every second row in CSV file, and put it next to the previous row

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file

```
1;(same.)
2;Type...
3; (who are you?)
4; I am a talker whom the world has not yet seen. And you?
5; (leave.)
6;Connect to the Internet - I'll leave...
7; (I would like to.)
8;He would like to! And you're a no-brainer guy!
```

The objective was to make it look like

```
row1 Question -  '(same.)' -  answer- 'Type...'
row2 Question -  '(who are you?)' -  answer- 'I am a talker whom the world has not yet seen. And you?
```

I am just learning, so it was hard for me.

**The feedback is much appreciated, how it can be done easier.**

final code

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
with open('answers.csv',mode='r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for line in reader:
        num = int(line[0])
        if num % 2:
            list1.append(line)
        if not num % 2:
            list2.append(line)
# print(list1)
# print(list2)
for i,m in zip(list1,list2):
    print(f'Question {i[1]}, Answer {m[1]}')
```

Comment: Do you want to write back to a file with the new structure, or just use it to display questions and answers on the terminal?

Comment: Terminal is fine, the objective is mainly to combine every 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know it will be every other line and start with a Q, I would use Slicing with step parameter, that way you get every n'th item [::n].
Starting at 1 [1::] for the first list, starting at item 2 [2::] in the second list.

```
with open('answers.csv',mode='r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

for i, m in zip(reader[1::2], reader[2::2]):
    print(f'Question {i[1]}, Answer {m[1]}')
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not strictly necessary to build up lists. It is possible to implement a "streamed" version that runs a generator over lines of the open file.

Also, `csv` is of minimal help here: there are no special text-field delimiters like quotes, and there is only one field you care about - and there are no headers - so you might as well just do the trivial parsing yourself.

### Suggested

```
from typing import Iterator


def parse(filename: str = 'answers.csv') -> Iterator:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        while True:
            line = next(f, None)
            if line is None:
                break
            _, question = line.split(';', 1)
            line = next(f)
            _, answer = line.split(';', 1)
            yield question.rstrip(), answer.rstrip()


for question, answer in parse():
    print('?', question, '\n    >', answer)
```

### Output

```
? (same.) 
    > Type...
?  (who are you?) 
    >  I am a talker whom the world has not yet seen. And you?
?  (leave.) 
    > Connect to the Internet - I'll leave...
?  (I would like to.) 
    > He would like to! And you're a no-brainer guy!
```